# Как забрать ajax-ом data-у приходящую от сервера и передать все в objectManager yandex maps

Tags: ajax, yandex-maps-api, geojson

Есть дерево с чекбоксами , по клику в чекбокс формируется запрос на сервер , с сервера приходит `[ ]`.

С этим всё ок, так же все ок с примерами из песочницы, где ajax-ом  читается json файлик и отправляется в  `objectManager`.

Вопрос, как забрать данные от сервера на лету, т.е чекаем чекбоксы, жмём показать, данные выгружаются и попадают в `objectManager`.

Comment: После нажатия формируем запрос на сервер, получаем данные и добавляем в objectManager=) Что конкретно не получается? Можете предоставить код который вы написали?

Comment: @se0ga Конкретно не получается связка (результат уже полученный от сервера ) и обработка его ajax для передачи  objectManager. Процедура передачи через data.json не вызывает трудностей поскольку там явно указано "url:"data.json" ?, а хранить данные в этом  "data.json" я не могу , они не статичны

Comment: Если вы получили результат с сервера то вам уже не нужен ajax. Вы можете его добавить в objectManager. Если проблема стоит в том как получить нужные данные, то нужно поднять свой сервер, который как-то будет обрабатывать ваши параметры. И посылать с помощью $.ajax запрос с параметрами к этому серверу, а в ответ получать geojson. http://basicweb.ru/jquery/jquery_method_ajax.php Если вы покажете, что написано, то возможно будет проще разобраться.